# Express routers don't keep req params

Tags: node.js, express, routes

When you define an endpoint with `app.use('/users/:id', router)`, and then define a route in `router` like so:

```
router.get('/randomroute', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.params.id); // undefined
});
```

`req.params.id` is undefined.

`:id` is present in the url handled by this route, and you still make one HTTP request, so that doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: what do you mean by :id is in those urls? did you mean your route is /randomroute/:id ?

Comment: I mean that the URL to access this route is `/users/:id/randomroute` so `:id` should be accessible by `randomroute` somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code is a correct way to do that

```
app.use('/users', router)

router.get('/:id/randomroute', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.params.id);
});
```